# Why keeps View updating when adding photos from photo picker to my model in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, combine

I'm having issues trying to understand combine and publishers. I have a PhotoPicker that selects one ore more images from the photo library. These images should be added to my core data model. This is handled in my model class.

However, I ends up in an infinit loop that I don't understand. The View keeps updating and the onReceive method keeps executing over and over again making the View render again. Below is a sample code (without core data) that behaves the same

Sample code:

```
struct MyImage: Hashable {
    var id: String
    var uiImage: UIImage
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var images: [MyImage] = []
    
    func add(uiImage: UIImage) {
        let id = UUID().uuidString
        let image = MyImage(id: id, uiImage: uiImage)
        self.images.append(image)
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    
    @State var showPhotoPicker = false
    @State var pickerResult: [UIImage] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            ForEach(model.images, id: \.self) { image in
                Text(image.id)
            }
            
            Button(action: { showPhotoPicker.toggle() }) {
                Text("ADD")
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showPhotoPicker) {
                let config = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: PHPhotoLibrary.shared())
                PhotoPicker(configuration: config, pickerResult: $pickerResult)
            }
            
        }
        
        .onReceive(pickerResult.publisher, perform: { image in
            model.add(uiImage: image)
        })
    }
}

struct PhotoPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode)
    var presentationMode
    
    let configuration: PHPickerConfiguration
    
    @Binding var pickerResult: [UIImage]
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PHPickerViewController {
        let controller = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PHPickerViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    class Coordinator: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
      
        private let parent: PhotoPicker
        
        init(_ parent: PhotoPicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            
            self.parent.pickerResult = []
            
            results.forEach { (image) in
                
                if image.itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self)  {
                    image.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { (newImage, error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        } else {
                            self.parent.pickerResult.append(newImage as! UIImage)
                        }
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    print("Loaded Assest is not a Image")
                }
            }
            
            self.parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: What is PhotoPicker?

Comment: It's a custom SwiftUI implementation of PHPickerViewController. Added it above.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal, reproducible example for your problem would be:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var pickerResult: [Int] = [1]
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .onReceive(pickerResult.publisher, perform: { image in
                self.pickerResult.append(1)
                print(self.pickerResult.count)
            })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

So, why does this code ends up in an infinite loop? Let's start with a slightly changed version:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var pickerResult: [Int] = [1]
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .onReceive(pickerResult.publisher, perform: { image in
                print(image)
            })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

As you can see, the publisher of `pickerResult` will emit a value (here the `1`) if the array is not empty. Changing the state to

```swift
@State var pickerResult: [Int] = [1, 2]
```

would case the publisher emit two values (`1` and `2`).

And now comes the trouble: Each time the publisher emits a value, `onReceive` is called. And it's callback will add a value to the `pickerResult`, which in turn tells SwiftUI to redraw the view. If the view is redrawn, the publisher will again emit it's values. This will ends up in an infinite loop.

I highly recommend to separate your view and logic parts. Don't use the view's `onReceive` method to perform business logic.

Comment: Could you share some sample code how you should do that the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with some modifications. I don't know if it could have been done in a better way. But it works.

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private(set) var images: [MyImage] = []
    
    func didSelectImages(images: [UIImage]) {
        images.forEach { (uiimage) in
            add(uiImage: uiimage)
        }
    }
    
    private func add(uiImage: UIImage) {
        let id = UUID().uuidString
        let image = MyImage(id: id, uiImage: uiImage)
        self.images.append(image)
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    
    @State var showPhotoPicker = false
    
    var config: PHPickerConfiguration = {
        var config = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: PHPhotoLibrary.shared())
        config.selectionLimit = 3
        return config
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            ForEach(model.images, id: \.self) { image in
                Text(image.id)
            }
            
            Button(action: { showPhotoPicker.toggle() }) {
                Text("ADD")
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showPhotoPicker) {
                PhotoPicker(configuration: config, completionHandler: model.didSelectImages)
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```